# adapter holder on listener cannot be final

Tags: android, adapter, final

I need to add a progress listener to each element of the horizontal list view, how can I do that?

For each item I upload a file.

I wanna to do something like that but holder is not final, so I have an error.

```
public class UploadsViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayoutResourceId;
    List<Upload> listFileToUpload;

    public UploadsViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Upload> data) {
        this.mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.listFileToUpload = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.upload_item_image);
            holder.progressUpdate = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.progressUpdate);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Upload item = getItem(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getThumbnail(160, 160));
        item.setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(int progress) {
                holder.progressUpdate.setProgress(item.getProgress());
            }
        });
        holder.progressUpdate.setProgress(item.getProgress());
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        ProgressBar progressUpdate;
    }

    public void updateListFileToUpdate(List<Upload> listFileToUpload) {
        this.listFileToUpload = listFileToUpload;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listFileToUpload.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Upload getItem(int location) {
        return listFileToUpload.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Class Update.java

```
public class Upload {
    public String path;
    public String type;
    private int mProgress = 0;
    private ProgressListener mListener;

    public Upload(String path, String type) {
        this.path = path;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setProgressListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        mProgress = progress;
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return mProgress;
    }

    public Bitmap getThumbnail(int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

    private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while (
                (halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight &&
                (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth
            ) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public interface ProgressListener {
        public void onProgress(int progress);
    }

}
```

Class which updates the file:

```
public class TheFormFragment extends Fragment {

    private AmazonS3Client mS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(Config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, Config.AWS_SECRET_KEY));

    public static final int RESULT_PHOTO_DISK   = 10;
    public static final int RESULT_PHOTO_APN    = 100;
    public static final int RESULT_VIDEO_APN    = 1000;

    public static final String INTENT_PHOTO_APN_PATH = "INTENT_PHOTO_APN_PATH";
    public static final String INTENT_VIDEO_APN_PATH = "INTENT_VIDEO_APN_PATH";

    private List<Medias> mTheFormPictures; 

    private static Activity mActivity;
    private static ArrayList<Upload> mQueue;

    private KeyboardEventLinearLayout mLinearLayoutBackground;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayoutPublish;
    private TextView mTextViewPublish;
    private ImageView mImageViewPublish; // todo image du bouton
    private EditText mEditTextText;
    private TextView mTextViewTitle;
    private CircularImageView mCircularImageViewAvatar;
    private ImageButton mImageButtonClose;
    private ImageButton mImageButtonCamera;
    private ImageButton mImageButtonLibrary;

    private Tag[] mTags = null;
    private Range mAutocompleting;
    private LinearLayout mAutocompleteContainer;

    private HorizontalListView mUploadsList;
    private UploadsViewAdapter mUploading;
    /**Contains list of images, vidoe to update*/
    private List<Upload> listFileToUpload;

    private KeyboardEventLinearLayout.KeyboardListener mKeyboardListener = new KeyboardEventLinearLayout.KeyboardListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            if (mUploadsList != null) {
                mUploadsList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            if (mUploadsList != null) {
                mUploadsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };

    private class Range {
        public int start;
        public int end;
        public String value;

        public Range(int start, int end, String value) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int oldCount, int newCount) {
            String before = text.subSequence(0, start + newCount).toString();
            Range range = findEditingTag(before);
            autocompete(range);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    };

    private OnClickListener mAutocompleteItemClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Editable text = mEditTextText.getText();
            CharSequence tag = ((TextView) view).getText();
            text.replace(mAutocompleting.start, mAutocompleting.end, tag);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_the_form, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mTheFormPictures = new ArrayList<Medias>();
        mQueue = new ArrayList<Upload>();

        mS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Config.AWS_REGION));

        mLinearLayoutBackground = (KeyboardEventLinearLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutBackground);
        mLinearLayoutPublish = (LinearLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutPublish);

        mTextViewPublish = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublish);
        mTextViewTitle = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);

        mImageViewPublish = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPublish);

        mCircularImageViewAvatar = (CircularImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.circularImageViewAvatar);

        mEditTextText = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.editTextText);

        mImageButtonClose = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonClose);
        mImageButtonCamera = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamera);
        mImageButtonLibrary = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonLibrary);

        mAutocompleteContainer = (LinearLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.autocompleteLayout);

        mUploadsList = (HorizontalListView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.uploadsList);   
        listFileToUpload =new ArrayList<Upload>(); 
        mUploading = new UploadsViewAdapter(mActivity, R.layout.upload_item, listFileToUpload);
        mUploadsList.setAdapter(mUploading);

        mLinearLayoutBackground.setKeyboardListener(mKeyboardListener);

        configure();

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void configure() {
        AQuery aq = new AQuery(mActivity);

        ImageOptions options = new ImageOptions();
        //options.round         = 180;
        options.fileCache   = false;
        options.memCache    = true;
        //options.animation = AQuery.FADE_IN;

        User user = Preferences.getUser(mActivity);

        if (user != null) {
            mTextViewTitle.setText(user.getFirst_name() + " " + user.getLast_name());

            if (user.getAvatar() != null && user.getAvatar().length() > 0) {
                aq.id(mCircularImageViewAvatar).image(user.getAvatar(), options);
            }
        }

        StatusConfigTheForm configTheForm = Preferences.getConfigTheForm(mActivity);

        if (configTheForm != null) {
            Log.i("theform config success");

            Log.d("avatar: " + user.getAvatar() + " " + configTheForm.getBorderWidth());

            if (configTheForm.getColors().getBackground().length == 3) {
                mLinearLayoutBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getBackground())));
            }

            if (configTheForm.getColors().getBackgrounPublishButton().length == 3) {
                // mButtonPublish.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getBackgrounPublishButton())));

                // prepare
                int roundRadius = 6;

                // normal state
                GradientDrawable background_normal = new GradientDrawable();
                background_normal.setColor(Color.parseColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getBackgrounPublishButton())));
                background_normal.setCornerRadius(roundRadius);

                // pressed state
                GradientDrawable bacground_pressed = new GradientDrawable();
                bacground_pressed.setColor(Color.parseColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getBackgrounPublishButton()).replace("#", "#CC"))); // opacity
                bacground_pressed.setCornerRadius(roundRadius);                         

                // states (normal and pressed)
                StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
                states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, bacground_pressed);
                states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_pressed}, background_normal);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    mLinearLayoutPublish.setBackground(states); 
                } else {
                    mLinearLayoutPublish.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
                }
            }

            if (configTheForm.getColors().getBackgroundTextView().length == 3) {
                mEditTextText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getBackgroundTextView())));
            }

            if (configTheForm.getColors().getBorderColorPicture().length == 3) {
                mCircularImageViewAvatar.setBorderColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getBorderColorPicture())); 
            }

            // add color tag here

            if (configTheForm.getColors().getColorTextPublish().length == 3) {
                mTextViewPublish.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getColorTextPublish())));
            }

            if (configTheForm.getColors().getColorTextAttachment().length == 3) {
                mCircularImageViewAvatar.setBorderColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getColorTextAttachment()));    
            }

            if (configTheForm.getColors().getColorTextUser().length == 3) {
                mTextViewTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(Utils.getHexaColor(configTheForm.getColors().getColorTextUser())));
            }

            if (configTheForm.getBorderWidth() > 0) {
                mCircularImageViewAvatar.setBorderWidth(configTheForm.getBorderWidth() * Integer.valueOf(Float.valueOf(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density).intValue()));    
            }

            // pictures
            if (configTheForm.getPictures() != null) {
                String baseUrl = configTheForm.getUrlPicto() + configTheForm.getFolder() + File.separator;
                String ext = Utils.setExtension(mActivity, Config.PICTURE_EXTENSION);
                Pictures pics = configTheForm.getPictures();

                if (configTheForm.getPictures().getPictureBack() != null) {
                    aq.id(mImageButtonClose).image(baseUrl + pics.getPictureBack() + ext, options);     
                }

                if (configTheForm.getPictures().getPictureCamera() != null) {
                    aq.id(mImageButtonCamera).image(baseUrl + pics.getPictureCamera() + ext, options);      
                }

                if (configTheForm.getPictures().getPictureLibrary() != null) {
                    aq.id(mImageButtonLibrary).image(baseUrl + pics.getPictureLibrary() + ext, options);        
                }

                if (configTheForm.getPictures().getPicturePublish() != null) {
                    mImageViewPublish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    aq.id(mImageViewPublish).image(baseUrl + pics.getPicturePublish() + ext, options);      
                } else {
                    mImageViewPublish.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        mEditTextText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

    private Range findEditingTag(String text) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#[A-z0-9_]+$");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (match.find()) {
            String value = text.substring(match.start());
            return new Range(match.start(), match.end(), value);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void autocompete(Range range) {
        mAutocompleting = range;
        mAutocompleteContainer.removeAllViews();

        if (range != null && mTags != null) {
            String tag;
            for (int i = 0; i < mTags.length; i++) {
                tag = "#" + mTags[i].getName();
                if (tag.startsWith(range.value) && tag.equals(range.value) == false) {
                    addAutocompleteItem(tag);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void addAutocompleteItem(String text) {
        Drawable background = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.autocomplete_item);
        int textColor = mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.autocomplete_item_text);

        TextView view = new TextView(mActivity);
        view.setText(text);
        view.setTextColor(textColor);

        view.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        } else {
            view.setBackground(background);
        }

        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setOnClickListener(mAutocompleteItemClickListener);

        mAutocompleteContainer.addView(view);
    }

    private void updateProgress() {
        //int progress = 0;
        //for (Upload file: mUploading) {
        //  progress += file.getProgress();
        //}
        //progress /= mUploading.size();

        //mProgressBarFile.setProgress(progress);
        //mTextViewFileProgress.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.theform_text_file_progress), Integer.valueOf(progress).toString()));
    }

    private class S3PutObjectTask extends AsyncTask<Upload, Integer, S3TaskResult> {
        //private Dialog progressDialog;
        ObjectMetadata mMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();

        private String mS3Filename;
        private Upload mFile;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            updateProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            int progress = Integer.valueOf( (int) ((values[0] * 100) / mMetadata.getContentLength()) );

            mFile.setProgress(progress);
            updateProgress();

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        protected S3TaskResult doInBackground(Upload... files) {
            if (files == null || files.length != 1 || files[0] == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                mFile = files[0];
            }

            ContentResolver resolver = mActivity.getContentResolver();

            // The file location of the image selected.
            Uri selectedSource = Uri.parse(mFile.path);

            if (mFile.type.equals("image")) {
                String size = null;
                String fileSizeColumn[] = { OpenableColumns.SIZE };

                Cursor cursor = resolver.query(selectedSource, fileSizeColumn, null, null, null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) { 
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                    // If the size is unknown, the value stored is null.  But since an int can't be
                    // null in java, the behavior is implementation-specific, which is just a fancy
                    // term for "unpredictable".  So as a rule, check if it's null before assigning
                    // to an int.  This will happen often:  The storage API allows for remote
                    // files, whose size might not be locally known.

                    if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex)) {
                        // Technically the column stores an int, but cursor.getString will do the
                        // conversion automatically.
                        size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
                    }

                    cursor.close();
                }

                mMetadata.setContentType(resolver.getType(selectedSource));

                if (size != null) {
                    mMetadata.setContentLength(Long.parseLong(size));
                }
            }

            if (mMetadata.getContentType() == null) {
                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedSource.toString(), opt);

                mMetadata.setContentType(opt.outMimeType);
            }

            if (mMetadata.getContentLength() <= 0) {
                mMetadata.setContentLength(new File(selectedSource.toString()).length());
            }

            selectedSource = Uri.parse("file://" + selectedSource.toString().replace("content://", ""));

            S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();

            // Put the image data into S3.
            try {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                if (mFile.type.equals("image")) {
                    mS3Filename = Long.valueOf(cal.getTime().getTime()).toString() + ".jpg";    
                } else {
                    mS3Filename = Long.valueOf(cal.getTime().getTime()).toString() + ".mp4";
                }

                PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                    Config.getPictureBucket(cal.getTime().getTime()), mS3Filename,
                    resolver.openInputStream(selectedSource), mMetadata
                ).withGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
                    int total = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent pv) {
                        total += (int) pv.getBytesTransferred();
                        publishProgress(total);
                    }
                });

                mS3Client.putObject(por);

                result.setName(mS3Filename);

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                result.setName(null);
                result.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(S3TaskResult result) {
            //mProgressBarFile.setProgress(0);
            //mTextViewFileProgress.setText("");

            // AWS Error
            if (result != null && result.getErrorMessage() != null && result.getName() == null) {
                FastDialog.showDialog(mActivity, FastDialog.SIMPLE_DIALOG, result.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                // add picture name
                mTheFormPictures.add(new Medias(result.getName()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /** close activity **/
    public void close(View v) {
        mActivity.finish();
    }

    /** select picture **/
    public void selectPicture(View v) {
        //Intent intent;
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            intent = new Intent(); 
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        }*/

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setType("image/* video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PHOTO_DISK);
    }

    /** take picture **/
    public void tackePicture(View v) {
        ApnActivity.show(mActivity, RESULT_PHOTO_APN);
    }

    /** record video **/
    public void recordVideo(View v) {
        RecordVideoActivity.show(mActivity, RESULT_VIDEO_APN);
    }

    /** publish button **/
    public void publish(View v) {
        // object
        WebViewTheFormResult theFormResult = new WebViewTheFormResult(mEditTextText.getText().toString(), mTheFormPictures);

        if (theFormResult.isEmpty()) {
            FastDialog.showDialog(mActivity, FastDialog.SIMPLE_DIALOG, getString(R.string.theform_publish_error));
        } else {
            // intent
            Intent dataIntent = new Intent();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(WebViewActivity.INTENT_OBJECT, (Serializable) theFormResult);

            dataIntent.putExtras(bundle);

            mActivity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
            mActivity.finish();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static void actionOnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode != RESULT_PHOTO_APN && requestCode != RESULT_VIDEO_APN) {
            requestCode = RESULT_PHOTO_DISK;
        }

        switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_PHOTO_DISK:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 && data.getData() == null) {
                ClipData clipdata = data.getClipData();
                for (int i = 0, l = clipdata.getItemCount(); i < l; i++) {
                    onDiskResult(clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri());
                }
            } else {
                onDiskResult(data.getData());
            }
            break;
        case RESULT_PHOTO_APN:
            onApnPhotoResult(data);
            break;
        case RESULT_VIDEO_APN:
            onApnVideoResult(data);
            break;
        }
    }

    private static void onDiskResult(Uri selectedImage) {
        InputStream imageStream;
        try {
            File file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +
                "Android" + File.separator +
                "data" + File.separator +
                mActivity.getPackageName()
            );

            if (new File(file.getAbsolutePath()).exists() == false) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            imageStream = mActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap goodPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            String filePath = file.getAbsoluteFile().toString() + "/" + String.valueOf(Utils.uid()) + Config.PHOTO_TMP_NAME;

            try {
                //goodPicture = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath,  MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                goodPicture = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(goodPicture, 800, 600, false);
                goodPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            queueFile(filePath, "image");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    private static void onApnPhotoResult(Intent data) {
        String filePath = data.getExtras().getString(TheFormFragment.INTENT_PHOTO_APN_PATH);

        if (filePath.equals(Integer.valueOf(RESULT_VIDEO_APN).toString())) {
            RecordVideoActivity.show(mActivity, RESULT_VIDEO_APN);
        } else {
            queueFile(filePath, "image");
        }
    }

    private static void onApnVideoResult(Intent data) {
        String filePath = data.getExtras().getString(TheFormFragment.INTENT_VIDEO_APN_PATH);

        if (filePath.equals(Integer.valueOf(RESULT_PHOTO_APN).toString())) {
            ApnActivity.show(mActivity, RESULT_PHOTO_APN);
        } else {
            queueFile(filePath, "video");
        }
    }

    private static void queueFile(String filePath, String fileType) {
        mQueue.add(new Upload(filePath, fileType));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        fetchTags();

        while (mQueue.size() > 0) {
            uploadFile(mQueue.remove(mQueue.size() - 1));
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void uploadFile(Upload file) {
        new S3PutObjectTask().execute(file);
        listFileToUpload.add(file);
        mUploading.updateListFileToUpdate(listFileToUpload);
        mUploading.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void fetchTags() {
        Api.getTags(mActivity, new Api.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String json) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                mTags = gson.fromJson(json, Tag[].class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Don't make holder final. It will not help you. You also made item final in order to use it in onProgress. But that will not do either. You have to determine the right holder with getTag() and if you put position in the holder (as int variable) then you have the holder.position and you can get the right item again with a getItem(holder.position).

Comment: Please show the definition of your Upload class. Because you set an setProgressListener on it.

Comment: You introduced ProgressListener interface to be able to display the right position for every upload, even when swiping the views? You have simultaneous uploads? Where and how would such an upload process 'tell' the progress?

Comment: `ProgressBar progressUpdate;` I hate that because it makes it so difficult to understand your code. `ProgressBar progressBar;` would be a better choice.

Comment: i update my question with the function who 'tell' the progress

it's on a async task


You have simultaneous uploads yes i can have this. yes even swipe i have to show position of update

Comment: Sorry about quality of code it's a project that i just begin in a new job

Comment: `.withGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener()` you have that in the doInBackground of your asynctask. Is that a different ProgressListener ? As i would expect that you had to implement member function onProgress() there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be enough:

```
...
holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getThumbnail(160, 160));
final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
item.setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgress(int progress) {
        finalHolder.progressUpdate.setProgress(item.getProgress());
    }
});
finalHolder.progressUpdate.setProgress(item.getProgress());
```

Answer (score 1):

Think that you can remove `setProgressListener()` from Upload class. 
Instead add a ProgressBar variable and a method setProgressBar() to Upload.

In getView():

```
Upload upload = getItem(position )

upload.setProgressBar(holder.progressUpdate);
```

In Upload: `in setProgress()` you can now directly address the ProgressBar variable

this is the `setProgress()` that in your AsyncTask is called with `mFile.setProgress(progress);`

Instead of removing better out comment the function and the call.

Untested. Please test. This will not be much work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make holder final. It will not help you. You also made item final in order to use it in onProgress. But that will not do either. You have to determine the right holder with getTag() and if you put position in the holder (as int variable) then you can use holder.position to get the right item again with a getItem(holder.position)

Comment: You have to determine the right holder with getTag() 

it's already what i do no ? with else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }  ??

Comment: You have to determine the right holder in onProgress(). You are using an invalid reference to a holder. DONT MAKE IT FINAL and you will see that you HAVE to determine it first.

Comment: Yes i see that, you say that i can retrieve the right item from holder ok, but how can finalHolder.progressUpdate.setProgress(progress); in on progress ?

Comment: I need to update view retrieve the correct item not suffisant for my case

Comment: This is why I'm not a fan of anonymous classes. If you make ProgressListener it's on separate class, it may help you see how you need to pass in the required info instead of attempting to use final.

Comment: `I need to update view retrieve the correct item not suffisant for my case`. Why not? What do you have to do more then?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses all.

I resolved the problem like this:

```
public class UploadsViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    List<Upload> listFileToUpload;
    UploadsViewAdapter instanceUploadsViewAdapter;

    public UploadsViewAdapter(Context context,
            List<Upload> data) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.listFileToUpload = data;
        this.instanceUploadsViewAdapter = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.upload_item_image);
            holder.play = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.play);
            holder.progressUpdate = (ProgressBar) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.progressUpdate);
            holder.deleteFileUploaded = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.delete_file_uploaded);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Upload item = getItem(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getThumbnail(160, 160));
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        item.setProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgress(int progress) {
                //item.setProgress(progress);
                finalHolder.progressUpdate.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress==100){
                    finalHolder.image.setAlpha(1.0f);
                    finalHolder.progressUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else{
                    finalHolder.image.setAlpha(0.5f);
                    finalHolder.progressUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
        if(item.getProgress()==100){
            finalHolder.image.setAlpha(1.0f);
            finalHolder.progressUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            finalHolder.image.setAlpha(0.5f);
            finalHolder.progressUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.deleteFileUploaded.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listFileToUpload.remove(position);
                instanceUploadsViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        if(item.getType().equals(EnumTypeFile.IMAGE.getTypeFile())){
            holder.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            holder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        finalHolder.progressUpdate.setProgress(item.getProgress());


        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        ProgressBar progressUpdate;
        ImageView deleteFileUploaded;
        ImageView play;
    }

    public void updateListFileToUpdate(List<Upload> listFileToUpload) {
        this.listFileToUpload = listFileToUpload;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listFileToUpload.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Upload getItem(int location) {
        return listFileToUpload.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```