# How to get animation on listview Item in Adapter class?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, adapter

I had implemented `ListView` successfully. I have A `TextView` in my `ListView` item. So I'll get the textview click in adapter class. I am getting properly click also in `Adapter` class. But I want to animate the particular `TextView` on which I'll click, but it is not happening.Here is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder.floorNo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_floorno);
            holder.hidedLayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.hidedLayout);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        FloorDetailItem floorDetailItem = data.get(position);
        holder.floorNo.setText("Floor " + floorDetailItem.getFloor());

        holder.floorNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        holder.floorNo.startAnimation(leftWrite);
                        handler = new Handler();
                        holder.floorNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        handler.postDelayed(mChangeSplash, 1000);
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        });
        return row;
    }

    private Runnable mChangeSplash = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!isFinishing()) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                holder.hidedLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };
     class RecordHolder {
        TextView floorNo;
        LinearLayout hidedLayout;
    }

}
```

But I am getting in `OnClickListener()`,error in "holder". The error is follow as:- "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable holder defined in an enclosing scope"
And I can't make it final.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be creating a `global` variable, instead of `final`. It will get rid the error.

Because i dont know which `variable` in your code that got the error, i will give an example :

Create a normal, private (or else) variable just inside your class, so all methods can access it :

```
private String globalName;
```

And then, you can assign the variable in the getView :

```
globalName = getItem(position).getName();
```

**UPDATE**

Use the answer provided in this link for finaling a `holder` :

[adapter holder on listener cannot be final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932453/adapter-holder-on-listener-cannot-be-final)

Comment: and I can't make it global because after making it global. How I'll get the correct clicked position ??

Comment: "holder.floorNo." in this line, " holder.floorNo.startAnimation(leftWrite);"

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using

```
holder.floorNo.startAnimation(leftWrite);<br>
handler = new Handler();<br>
holder.floorNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);<br>
handler.postDelayed(mChangeSplash, 1000);<br>
```

You can simply refer the view v which is a parameter of onclick which is same as holder.floorNo

do like this

```
v.startAnimation(leftWrite);<br>
handler = new Handler();<br>
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);<br>
handler.postDelayed(mChangeSplash, 1000);<br>
```

Hop it will remove your error.